# Insert images into wordpress post with a query

Tags: wp-query, images, query

I have a Wordpress installation with 2.000 posts. Also in a separate table of my database I have a set of image paths and the filenames of the images, each image is assigned to each post of my Wordpress installation based on the post id.

eg of my images' table

```
id|image
--------
1 | img1.png
2 | secondimage.jpg
...
2014| onemoreimage.gif
```

Is it possible to execute an SQL query or a Wordpress API call to insert each image as featured image of each post based on the ID?
Also where should I upload the original image files?
Thanks in advance

Comment: isn't it a sql query like: SELECT * FROM <your table> WHERE id=<$post->ID> what gives you all the images?

Comment: I dont't have a problem extracting the images but inserting them in the Wordpress db schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, WordPress does not have an API, but some useful functions.

I would load all your rows into array like

```
$your_table = ['post_id' => 'image', 'post_id' => 'image', …]
```

Then execute a foreach loop

```
foreach($your_table as $post_id => $image)
{
    //full path to the image
    $image_path = _YOUR_FULL_ABSOLUTE_PATH.$image;

    /**
      * Get an ID of the inserted attachment
      * This takes care of resizing image and stuff…
      * The fourth param I would sugest you to keep true, since in case of duplicate entry in your table, it will not have been inserted more than once
      */
    $featured_image = wp_insert_attachment(array('attachment_meta'), $image_path, $post_id, true);

    //assign featured image
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $featured_image);
}
```

'attachment_meta' study [`here`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)